# Working out the work done to place 3 electrons in an equilateral triangle query

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

In my problem sheet we were given this past exam problem. I just wanted to check my reasoning because my methods length doesn't seem proportional to the marks given.

[image]

If you imagine placing the electrons one by one, the work done to place the first electron in space is 0, the work done to place the second electron is $ke^2/a$ where $k=1/4\pi \epsilon_0 $. The work done to place the third electron is $2ke^2/a$. The total work done is $3ke^2/a$. This seems wrong because there would be more than $ke^2/a$ worth of work to bring the second charge a distance $a$ away from the first, since they both repel each other. Likewise for bringing the 3rd charge into the system.

Another thought was just to sum the potential energy of each electron which looks like its $2ke^2/a$ and get the total potential energy of the system to be $6ke^2/a$, which would be the work done to bring it together.

Both of these methods seem too simplistic for question, whats the appropriate reasoning to use?

Comment: I guess while calculating potential energy you are counting the interactions twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like while calculating potential energy you are counting the interactions twice.

However, $W = U_{net} = U_{12}+U_{13}+U_{31} = \dfrac{3ke^2}{a}$ as noted from your earlier arguement.

> This seems wrong because there would be more than $ke^2/a$ worth of work to bring the second charge a distance $a$ away from the first since they both repel each other.

Well, no. Coulomb potential is given by $$U(r) = \int F(r) \  \mathbb{d}r = - \dfrac{q_1q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}\int {\dfrac{1}{r^2} \ \mathbb{d}r} = \dfrac{q_1q_2}{4\pi \epsilon_{0}}\dfrac{1}{r} $$ For our case, $U_{net} = ke^2/a$ for each pair of electrons. There are $3$ such pairs.

As long as no other forces are involved you don't need extra energy to 'fix' the electron in place.

Comment: But if i were to actually try and place another electron a distance $a$ away from another, wouldnt I have to try and spend some energy fixing the other electron in place, because it would move out as I pushed the other electron in, if that makes sense. In that case should we try use the reduced mass or some other calculation because I feel the energy to move the charge $a$ away is larger than $ke^2/a$

Comment: That energy you should spend must be supplied in order to overcome the repulsion between the two. We needn't use anything else.